# I have multiple workbooks, with 1 Worksheets The format of Sheet are same in all Workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I have to copy the checked options button caption to the destination. I would like to write a VBA code that would do the following: In a single Master.xlsm Sheet1:

[image: Exxample Inzmge]

a. Copy the value of A2,B2,C5,E5, F7,etc in Sheet 1 of WorkBook1, paste it in B2,C2,D2,E2,F2...(same row) of Master.xlsm

b. Copy the Checked OptionButton caption in Sheet 1 of WorkBook1, and paste it in B2 of Master. xlsm

c. Copy the value of I12, L12, N12 (YYYY/MM/DD) in Sheet 1 of WorkBook1, and paste it in D2 of Master. xlsm

This is the code I tried: which doesn't really work:

```
Dim Wsh As New IWshRuntimeLibrary.WshShell
Dim result As WshExec
Dim fileData() As Variant
Dim path As String
Dim cmd As String
Dim strData As Variant

path = ThisWorkbook.path & "\Test"
cmd = "dir" & path & "/Test"
Set result = Wsh.Exec("%ComSpec% /c" & cmd)

Do While result.Status = 0
    DoEvents
Loop
fileData = Split(result.StdOut.ReadAll, vbCrLf)
Dim i As Long
i = 2
For Each strData In fileData
    Cells(i, 2).Value = strData

    If Cells(i, 2).Value <> "" Then
        Cells(i, 3).Value = "='" & path & "\[" & strData & "]sheet1'!A2"
        Cells(i, 4).Value = "='" & path & "\[" & strData & "]sheet1'!B2"

        Cells(i, 6).Value = "='" & path & "\[" & strData & "]sheet1'!C5"
        Cells(i, 7).Value = "='" & path & "\[" & strData & "]sheet1'!E5"
        Cells(i, 9).Value = "='" & path & "\[" & strData & "]sheet1'!C8"
    End If
    i = i + 1
Next
```

Comment: You want to copy the values, or create formulas (as in your code)? to c) you want to combine four cell values into one cell?

Comment: I would like to copy the data value (i.e: yyyy/mm/dd) of three cells as the date on the destination range.

Comment: So I12, L12 and N12 contain year, month and day? Maybe check _DateSerial_ to generate the date from different cell values.

Comment: Thank You. How can I copy the options button caption to the next workbook?